# send HTTP Get request using Curl in c

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

Please help me to implement an HTTP Get request using curl in C.

I need to hit URL with parameters  like  https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users?name=pradeep&lastname=singla
I used `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to set parameters with Header but without success. I implemented it like

```
struct curl_slist* contentheader = NULL;    

contentheader = curl_slist_append(contentheader, "name=pradeep");
contentheader = curl_slist_append(contentheader, "lastname=singla");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, contentheader);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

In this case an error occured like "no correct APi request". So I thought that I can use

```
char *charff = "name=pradeep&lastname=singla";    
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, charfff);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L); curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

but the same error is occurring.

Can anyone please help me ?  I can put my request for both POST and GET method because server method may change anytime.

Comment: Why not simply add the parameters to the URL, like it's usually done? Like exactly what you have in the URL you show (`https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users?name=pradeep&lastname=singla`).

Answer (score 3):

The URL is just a URL even with "parameters" and you set it in full with [CURLOPT_URL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html).

They're not headers and they're not postfields.

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users?name=pradeep&lastname=singla");
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Comment: in future if the server HTTP method get changed to POST than i have to send parameter using POST method so i am thinking the way i don't need to worry in future for method. just need a solution that can handle both cases (GET and POST)